# wpf resource dictionary does not exist in namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using .net 4.5.2
I do not have a clue why my project continues to say the resource is missing. I've paced my mainWindow.xaml inside a folder and repathed the app to target its location. What is really odd is the fact that it displays correctly in visual studio but when i try to compile it errors out saying the 'themes' namespace does not exist in the project.

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0234  The type or
>   namespace name 'Themes' does not exist in the namespace
>   'WpfApplication1' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   WpfApplication1 C:\Users\jmartini\Projects\wpf_Styling_4.5.2\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\Debug\View\MainWindow.g.i.cs   33

Here is my code...

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="250"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Push It!" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**JMStyles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Themes">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="View/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/JMStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

**Solution to get it working...**
I removed this line from the style page:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Themes"
```

original

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this line of code

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Themes"
```

from the style page file contents below...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Themes">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Windows.Themes is found in the theme-specific PresentationFramework assemblies. You'll need to add a reference to one of the following depending on which one is referenced in your XAML:

```
PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
PresentationFramework.AeroLite.dll
PresentationFramework.Classic.dll
PresentationFramework.Luna.dll
PresentationFramework.Royale.dll
```

Comment: I'm creating my own custom theme though. It errors when i add my custom theme to the app.xaml.

Comment: You need to add the theme resource dictionary to the MergedDictionaries collection. Example is shown below.                                                                        <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlack.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- other resources go here -->

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocatorKey"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

Comment: Did you check  the version of .NET between the assembly and the project (.NET 4.5.2 client profile and .NET non client)

Comment: where do i check those at?

Comment: If you think you're running the most up to date version of VS2012 and still experiencing this issue, make absolutely sure that the update has been applied if you had updated using Windows Update,you need to  to tell VS2012 to apply the update.

Comment: im running 2015. but where do i check the .net being used in the assembly vs the project?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Visual Studio doesn't recognize namespaces of folders with only Resource Dictionary files. If you add another file in that folder like a User Control you would notice that the namespace would be recognized. The solution is to remove the line of 
"local" namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Themes
```

because we will mention the resourse with

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/...
```

Without needing the namespace, in difference when we create User Controls that we do need the namespace in the code of the file where they're used